# how to set ENV variables from a file during jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I want to set up a Job in Jenkins. Before start of the build we have file (.xyz)from which we set up our env variables required for the build.

Manually build works fine but when i try to run that file inside the jenkins shell it doesnt set up any env variables. is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It **does** set it, however:

1. You cannot see it outside of Jenkins (these changes are transient)
2. They only last for the duration of that *Execute Shell* that set them, and any other build/post-build step won't have them.

This is by design, this is how Jenkins maintains a clean environment that doesn't effect the rest of the machine.

To be able to set them, ***and retain*** them between build steps, you need [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).
Using that plugin, you can configure environment variables (either manually, through script, or through a file), and this can be done at various intervals, such as before the SCM checkout, as a build step, etc.